# AWS CodeBuild Unable to "go get" a package

Tags: go, aws-codebuild

I have an AWS CodeBuild job, defined with the following buildspec file (apologies if indentation isn't reproduced correctly):

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
      PACKAGE: "github.com/user/package" 
phases:
  install: 
      commands:
          - mkdir -p ${GOPATH}/src/${PACKAGE}
          - cp -a ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR}/.  ${GOPATH}/src/${PACKAGE}
          - cd ${GOPATH}/src/${PACKAGE} && go get ./...
build:
     commands:
          - cd ${GOPATH}/src/${PACKAGE} && go build -o ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR}/application
post_build:
    commands:
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yml --output-template-file serverless.yml --s3-bucket some-bucket
artifacts:
  files:
    - serverless.yml
```

This fails in the install phase.

The go application I'm trying to build has several sub-packages and external dependencies.  When running "go get ./..." I'm getting

```
cannot find package github.com/user/package/sub-package in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/github.com/user/package/sub-package(from $GOROOT) /go/src/github.com/user/package/sub-package(from $GOPATH) /codebuild/output/src708017258/src/github.com/user/package/sub-package
```

When "debugging" (by putting in some echos and listing the contents of the newley created folders) it *appears* that everything is in the right place and everything should just work.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I'm using AWS code pipeline to build a Go application but it seems that AWS Codebuilds that use Code Pipeline as a source lose their credentials for connecting to github.  Were you able to find a work around?